# Save features created with leaflet.draw to comptuer

Tags: draw, leaflet, geojson

I am working on a leaflet map and I want to use leaflet.draw plugin to provide the option to the user to draw vector and markers. Next, I would like to offer the option to the user to save the vectors/markers to their computer (e.g., as geojson). I am looking for pointers and examples how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get all the features into a `LayerGroup`, then you could call `toGeoJSON()` on it - see http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-togeojson. The results of that could then be given to [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) for a client-side download, like

```
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(result)], {type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "features.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
editCoord <- function(){
  pgn <- NULL
  if(length(input$map_draw_all_features$features) != 0) {
    if(unique(unlist(lapply(input$map_draw_all_features$features, function(x){x$geometry$type}))) == "Polygon") {
      for(j in 1:length(input$map_draw_all_features$features)){
        geo <- unlist(lapply(input$map_draw_all_features$features[j], function(x){x$geometry$coordinates}))
        v <- seq(1, length(geo), 2)
        n <- length(geo)/2 
        for (i in 1:n) {  
          xy <- c(geo[v[i]], geo[i*2])
          if (i == n) break()
          pgn <- c(pgn, paste0(xy[1]," ",xy[2],","))
        }
        pgn <- c(pgn, paste0(xy[1]," ",xy[2]))
      }
      cat(pgn, "\n", file=paste0("f", input$usertext))
      readLines(paste0("f", input$usertext))
    }
  } 
}
```

```
editPlot <- function(){
  db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = "watsan", host = options()$rds$host, 
                  port = options()$rds$port, user = options()$rds$user, 
                  password = options()$rds$password)
  # Construct the update query
  query <- paste0('UPDATE plots SET `geom_plot`= ST_GeomFromText("POLYGON((',"",Coord(),"",'))") WHERE `parcel_id`=',"'",  ID() ,"'",';')
  query <- gsub('\"', "'", query)
  # Submit the fetch query and disconnect
  dbGetQuery(db, query)
  dbDisconnect(db)
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.